# When to use '', "", «», — or italic?

Tags: significado, sinais-gráficos

1. Apostrophes (`''`);
2. Quotation marks (`""`);
3. Chain quotes (`«»`, are these really french quotes ([*aspas francesas*](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/italico-e-aspas/13456)) in Portuguese? Why?!);
4. Dash (`—`, I believe this is called [*travessão*](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/travess%C3%A3o), is there a difference between the [en dash `—` and the em dash `–` in Portuguese](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1620/difference-between-the-en-dash-and-em-dash)?)
5. Italicized words (*italic*)...

From what I know, these are ways to refer to something that:

- was either said or written by someone else (quotation);
- indicates a foreign word/expression to the language;
- suggests [another meaning or the opposite of the real meaning of the word](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/artigos/rubricas/idioma/sobre-o-bom-uso-das-aspas/3042) (does this only happen with quotation marks?).

In which cases should I use each set of symbols in Portuguese? Or *italic* instead of these? Examples would be a plus.

### Português

1. Plicas, comas/aspas simples (`''`);
2. Aspas (`""`);
3. [Aspas francesas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/italico-e-aspas/13456) (`«»`, porque são assim chamadas?!);
4. Travessão (`—`, existe alguma diferença entre [`—` e `–` em Português](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1620/difference-between-the-en-dash-and-em-dash)?)
5. *Itálico*...

De acordo com o que encontrei, estes são métodos para:

- expressar algo dito ou escrito por alguém (quotações);
- introduzir uma palavra ou expressão estrangeira;
- sugerir [outro significado ou o significado oposto da palavra](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/artigos/rubricas/idioma/sobre-o-bom-uso-das-aspas/3042) (será que isto apenas acontece com as aspas (duplas)?).

Em que casos se devem utilizar um determinado conjunto deste tipo de sinais? Ou em que casos se deve utilizar *itálico* para os substituir? Agradeceria exemplos.

Comment: « » are quotation marks. They are more commonly used in Portugal (and maybe Africa?), whereas “ ” are used more commonly in Brazil. They are otherwise equivalent. I'm not sure why they'd surprise you, « » are the norm/preferred in Romance languages (see Spanish, Italian, French, and the multitude of minority languages spoken sound them, although Romanian prefers German-style). You should probably also include the dialogue indicator — here for completeness.

Comment: @guifa I wonder whether you are mistaken. I'm a lot more familiar with raised "aspas" than with this « ». I had to copy them from your comment: don't know how to type them. I had a look at four of the main Portuguese newspapers, and all of them use raised "aspas".

Comment: About `«` and `»`: Wikipedia calls them "[angular quotes](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspas)"; *they're how I learned to quote* in school (very early nineties), but nowadays the raised quotes are more commonly used in Portugal; the pt-PT keyboard has a single key only for the angular quotes (top right, next to backspace), but the pt-BR one does not: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portuguese_keyboard_layout

Comment: @Armfoot, do you want a generic Portuguese-language answer, or specifically an european-Portuguese or Brasilian-Portuguese one?

Comment: @ANeves the more the merrier I guess :)

Comment: @Jacinto it's possible usage is changing, but isn't the «» key on your keyboard? If Portugal is switching to preferring “ ”, that's a shame. «» look *so much better* with Romance languages. Do the keyboards sold in Portugal no longer have a «» key? What was it replaced with?

Comment: They do actually. Funny I didn't see them when I went looking for them! Had to follow ANeves instructions. ««»»««»»

Comment: No Brasil nunca conseguimos digitar a tal da aspas francesas nos teclados EUA ou Brasileiros (layouts mais comuns no Brasil).

Comment: They are French quote marks in English too. English does not have « quote marks ».English has this type of quote mark: "quotes".

Answer (score 11):

Uma das coisas que há que ter em conta é que o Acordo Ortográfico não especifica muito os usos, porém, muitas vezes é questão de estilo. (E cada editorial terá o seu próprio livro de estilo.)

### As aspas duplas

As aspas duplas, tanto as «angulares» como as curvas “b”, usam-se para fazer citações em textos. Nos periódicos, são as mais usadas para citar o que diz a gente. Em alguns estilos, uma citação dentro doutra usará a outra forma, alternando-as quando houver mais níveis de citações:

> O crítico diz «não posso acreditar que o autor escreva “dois e dois fazem cinco”».

Nalguns estilos são usadas para títulos de poemas, de contos curtos, e de peças curtas de teatro.
Também é possível usá-las para designar ironia.

Existe ainda uma forma "reta", comum na programação, que se deve evitar nos textos publicados.

Tradicionalmente, no Brasil usam-se só as curvas e em Portugal, as angulares.  Segundo os comentários, parece que o uso em Portugal se vai aproximando do brasileiro.

### Aspas simples

Quase sempre na forma curva, usam-se, segundo estilo, para designar uma citação noutra ou para os títulos de obras curtas. A aspa simples curva fechada coincide em forma com o apóstrofo.

Existe também uma forma reta `'`, comum na programação, que se deve evitar nos textos publicados.

### Travessões

Nas obras literárias, usam-se para designar o início de diálogo (quase sempre no começo da linha) e para designar o fim do mesmo:

> — Onde fica o castelo?
>   — Não sei. Vamos até ao centro. Talvez lá o encontremos.

Também é possível usá-lo para designar um texto parentético que seja mais importante do que um texto que ficasse entre parêntesis, ou para assinalar uma mudança brusca de pensamento no texto:

> Eu estou a falar dos melhores cães de caça — os do meu amigo — que vi na minha vida.

Dependendo do «estilo de casa», pode ou não haver espaço antes ou depois do travessão.

### Meias-riscas

Soem usar-se em textos publicados com tipografia óptima para designar uma ruptura breve do diálogo:

> — Maria – disse-me João – és uma pessoa muito interessante.

, e também quando uma das duas entidades entre hífen tenha mais de duas palavras:

> cor verde-azul marino <sub>(variante marina de *verde-azul*)</sub>
>   cor verde–azul marino <sub>(mistura de *verde* com a variante marina de *azul*)</sub>

Dependendo do «estilo de casa», pode ter espaço ou não. Mas são coisas mais para tipógrafos. Para a maioria da gente, no diálogo só se usa o travessão, e para unir/contrapor duas coisas só se usa o hífen.

### Itálico

Em obras, o uso de itálico indica que não é um conto curto ou artigo, senão um romance ou uma monografia; não é um poema normal, mas um poema épico; etc. Sói ser usado para palavras estrangeiras ou para palavras usadas como tal:

> Essa canção tem um estilo muito *ska*.
>   A palavra *a* pode ser artigo ou preposição.

Existe um espaço cinzento entre quando usar itálico ou aspas (obviamente, podemos ter um conto longo ou um romance curto, por exemplo), mesmo com citar palavras porque às vezes é normal pôr em itálico locuções curtas:

> A palavra inglesa *run* pode significar *correr*, *funcionar*, ou às vezes *soltar um líquido*.

É usado para dar ênfase a uma palavra:

> Essa menina é *muito* inteligente.

Às vezes nas obras literárias, o itálico é usado para designar os pensamentos das personagens (em contraste com o que dizem em voz alta), ou em textos de referência, para citar exemplos:

> O homem mirava a mulher.  *Ela é muito bela*, pensava.  *Oxalá fosse a minha namorada.*  Começou a falar com ela.
>   — Bom dia senhora!
>   Ela ficou surpreendida. *O que faz este homem tão pobre falando comigo?!* Voltou para casa sem lhe dizer nenhuma palavra.

Quando há algo em itálico que precisa de outra coisa também em itálico dentro dela, em vez de se fazer o itálico (ainda) mais oblíquo, põe-se o texto romano de novo.

> Eis aqui um exemplo do inglês com ênfase: *The building is* really *tall*.

Porém, não é recomendável ter vários níveis de coisas em itálico porque pode ser difícil perceber se o texto romano fica dentro ou fora do texto itálico.

Comment: Tu usas um verbo que eu não entendo: «Soer»? «Soem usar-se em textos publicados»? Depois tu tens os teus exemplos em itálico, e que dizes estar em itálico está me romano, o que fica muito confuso. Imagino que seja o teu «estilo da casa»,

Comment: @Jacinto **Soer**: *Ter por costume; ser frequente. = COSTUMAR*.  Quando tens «itálico» dentro texto itálico, torna-se romano.  Vou mudar os exemplos na seção de itálico para fazer as coisas mais claras

Comment: @Jacinto aparentemente *soer* não é usado no português tanto quanto o seus cognados em outras línguas românicas.  =/

Comment: guifa, travessão é uma palavra masculina, como todas as palavras acabadas em `-ão`. Ão pode ser (neste caso é) um aumentativo masculino. O aumentativo feminino pode ser `-ona` (aldrabona), `-ã` (irmã), `-oa` (patroa), etc... (Podes encontrar [mais exemplos](http://www.flip.pt/FLiP-On-line/Gramatica/Morfologia-Partes-do-discurso/Genero/Feminino-dos-substantivos-e-dos-adjectivos) online.) Espero que isto ajude. :)

Comment: É uma ótima resposta, bom trabalho guifa!

Comment: @Aneves obrigado!

Answer (score 7):

A forma de uso no Brasil que mais vejo é a seguinte:

“Aspas curvas” para citações na escrita à mão ou texto digitado mais elaborado. "Aspas retas" em texto digitado quando não houver suporte do *software* para convertê-las em aspas curvas, já que o teclado normalmente contém apenas as aspas retas. As aspas também podem indicar ironia ou o significado oposto como foi dito na pergunta.

‘Aspas simples’ em alguns casos raros, como uma citação dentro de outra (aparece de vez em quando em jornais). Em geral pensa-se em ’ ou ' como um apóstrofo e não aspa.

«Aspas francesas/angulares» nunca (eu utilizo às vezes por clareza, como na frase “O símbolo «'» é utilizado como apóstrofo ou aspas simples blá blá blá....”, mas esse é um uso pessoal). Esses símbolos não existem no teclado brasileiro, nem são populares.

— Travessão no começo de cada linha, especialmente para diálogos. Serve também para terminar a fala citada e voltar ao texto (portanto circundando o texto citado — e também servindo como uma maneira de incluir notas, semelhante a parênteses ou texto entre vírgulas). Não existe no teclado padrão brasileiro, exigindo algum suporte do *software*, mas quando eu estava na escola (anos 90), escrevendo à mão e lendo livros de literatura era bem popular. Código Unicode: U+2014.

– Este símbolo se chama meia-risca (mais curto que o travessão e mais longo que o hífen). Seu modo correto de uso, comparado com o travessão, só deve ser bem conhecido por pessoas que trabalham com publicação profissional. Este é o símbolo escolhido pela conversão automática de processadores de texto (como o Word) quando se encontra um hífen com espaços ao redor. Tecnicamente é diferente do travessão mas informalmente deve servir bem como um genérico “traço maior que o hífen” :-) Código Unicode: U+2013

*Itálico* para palavras estrangeiras ou ênfase.