# Difference between the en dash — and em dash –

Tags: sinais-gráficos

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash):

> (...) **en dashes are used with spaces** and **em dashes** are used **without them**:[2]
>
> - [Em dash:] A flock of sparrows—some of them juveniles—alighted and sang.
> - [En dash:] A flock of sparrows – some of them juveniles – alighted and sang.
>
> The **en** dash (but not the em dash) is also used to indicate spans or
>   differentiation, where it may be considered to **replace "and" or "to"**
>   (but not "to" in the phrase "from … to …"):[3]
>
> - The French and Indian War (1754–1763) was fought in western Pennsylvania and along the present US–Canadian border (Edwards, pp.
>     81–101).
>
> The **em** dash (but not the en dash) is also used to set off the **sources of quotes**:
>
> - "Seven social sins: politics without principles, wealth without work, pleasure without conscience, knowledge without character,
>     commerce without morality, science without humanity, and worship
>     without sacrifice." —Mahatma Gandhi

Are these dashes different in Portuguese? I.e. do they have different meanings and contexts? If so, do they also have the same spacing rule?

Comment: A useful base for an answer: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meia-risca

Comment: @ANeves wow, thanks! _Meia-risca_ is completely new to me, in that page they reference [ciberduvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/o-uso-do-hifen-e-do-travessao/31251) which calls it _traço de ligação_.

Comment: I just tried to see what they had in [https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/–](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/–) and [https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/—](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/—) :) And it was the first time I read or heard "meia-risca", as well.

Comment: Curiously, neither site that's cited for the em dash beside en dash actually says anything with respect to using disagree with en and not with em.

Answer (score 2):

**Em dash**

In literacy it is used to begin a dialog(almost always at the beggining of a line) and to end the sentence as well:

— Where is the castle?

— I don't know. Let's go to the mall. Maybe we'll find it there.

Also it is possible to use for a sentence that is written between brakets, and instead of the brakets you use the em dashes. Or to indicate a severe change in thought:

I'm talking about the best dog hunters -my friend's dogs- that I've seen in my life.

**En dashes**

Indicates a break in the dialog:

— Mary – told me John– you're a very interesting person.

**Hyphens**

Are used when breaking apart the current word writing at the end of a line:

[image: See text]

**Translation:**
When I got home *I found* a dead body lying on the floor. It looked like a *murder*. I wanted to call the cops, but the phone line *was* cutted off, so I left home to find a payphone and as soon as I reach the door a man came *to me*, but I was scared so I shooted him. That's why I'm in prison.

Also when the whole word is made up of two words that are separated with the hyphen, but is considered a single word:

cor verde-azul (colour green-blue)
It is actually the name of a colour in portuguese

Comment: Aren't hyphens, instead of en dashes, used inside words?

Comment: Hyphens and en dashes are the same thing

Comment: No they aren't... this is a hyphen: " - " and this is an en dash: " – ". The en dash is longer. Do you have any source that indicates they're used the same in Portuguese? The Portuguese Wikipedia says [they shouldn't be confused with each other.](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%ADfen#N.C3.A3o_confundir)

Comment: You mean that the em dashes are the same as hyphens?

Comment: No, em dashes are longer than en dashes (like how the letter m is longer than n), so they're definitely not the same as hyphens, which are shorter than en dashes.

Comment: In order, you have hyphen, n-dash, and m-dash seen between quotes: " - – — ".  It's possible to see all three together in one line (though certainly rare and generally only in well type set novels)

Comment: Boa parte desta resposta é uma tradução [desta outra resposta](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1613/when-to-use-or-italic/1628#1628) sem indicação de fonte.

Comment: @InêsBarataFeioBorges como disse o Jacinto a sua reposta é, em parte, uma tradução da outra sem indicação da fonte. Agradecia que colocasse a indicação da fonte, porque assim como está é considerado plágio.