# dash, short dash, long dash

Tags: etimologia

I know that a dash is "travessão". What would you call short dash (en dash) and what would you call long dash (em dash)?

I tried wikipedia, but it doesn't have entry for that in Portuguese.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash

I have also found a topic here but without its translation:

[Difference between the en dash — and em dash –](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1620/difference-between-the-en-dash-and-em-dash)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

- **"en dash"**

  > A [**meia-risca**](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meia-risca), também chamada de **traço de ligação**, **meio-traço** ou **traço médio** é um sinal de pontuação que serve para unir os valores extremos de uma série, como números, letras ou outras, indicando ausência de intervalos na enumeração. Serve igualmente para unir palavras que tenham um nexo lógico. (ex.: a viagem Lisboa–Porto). Esta opção é particularmente útil quando uma das palavras é composta e já tem hífens (ex.: Linda-a-Velha–Lisboa).

Não confundir - a meia-risca não é o mesmo que o hífen ou o travessão.

- **"em dash"**

> [**sinal escrito para separar frases ou introduzir perguntas**](http://www.wordreference.com/enpt/em%20dash)

[**Este site**](http://www.linguee.com.br/ingles-portugues/traducao/an+em+dash.html) cita várias frases onde "em dash" foi traduzido como **"traço"**.

Já os dicionários online que consultei traduzem "em dash" apenas como **travessão**

Comment: and is there a general word for dash in Portuguese?

Comment: @cornejo   Quando "dash" refere-se à língua escrita, geralmente é traduzido como "travessão".  Ocasionalmente,  em outros contextos, poderá ser "traço".