# Por que não existem os sinais ¿ e ¡ na língua portuguesa?

Tags: pontuação

Por que não temos os sinais ¿ e ¡ nas perguntas e exclamações na língua portuguesa, se ficaria muito mais fácil de se ler um texto?

Às vezes, começamos a ler uma pergunta, e ela tem várias linhas num texto, e pensamos que é uma afirmação; no entanto, ao chegarmos ao final dessa pergunta, nos deparamos com um ponto de interrogação.

Por que não devemos usar esse tipo de pontuação, e quem deveria determinar que devemos usar para que seja considerado certo o uso?

Em espanhol não temos esse problema, e em português, até mesmo quando uma pessoa importante, como um governador, precisa ler um texto do tipo, se sente envergonhado de não ter lido como "convinha".

Comment: Bom, a resposta real é que o orçamento não chega para esses sinais extra, por causa de todo o dinheiro desperdiçado nos bail-outs... mas isso ninguém tem coragem de dizer, porque foge à linha narrativa definida centralmente. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Porque nenhum órgão ou instituição tomou a decisão de (tentar) adotar esses símbolos - nem os usuários da língua os adotaram organicamente.

No caso do espanhol foi a *Real Academia* que, em 1754, os introduziu em sua "*Ortografía*", conforme as respostas à pergunta, no Spanish SE,
[Origin and usage of “¿” and “¡”](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/137/origin-and-usage-of-and):

> it was implemented in 1754 on the second edition of Ortografía de la real academia

Interessante notar que a adoção dos sinais foi gradual, e que eles podem ser usados em conjunto:

> It was introduced in the Grammar in 1754 but was not generally used until years later.
>
> You can start with one sign (¡) and close with the other (?) if the meaning is mixed, but using both is preferred.

Comment: Stafusa, mas será que a ABL é tão responsável assim? Digo, a Real Academia Espanhola e a Academia Francesa regulam em parte a própria língua, mas nunca vi a ABL regulando a língua. O VOLP (https://www.academia.org.br/nossa-lingua/busca-no-vocabulario?sid=19), por exemplo, não é oficial ou lei. O VOC (https://voc.cplp.org/) é oficial, mas não o VOLP. Nenhum dos dois é 100% responsável, já que muita gente escreve “mussarela”, o que está tudo bem. Por sinal, posso estar implicando com aquilo que não importa muito, em relação à tua resposta.

Comment: @Schilive Bom ponto, obrigado, já corrigi e removi a menção à ABL. Acho que devido ao seu papel prominente no Acordo Ortográfico de 1990, eu tinha ficado com a impressão de que ela tinha um papel mais relevante nesse tipo de questão.

Comment: Stafusa, de nada. Mas é uma boa pergunta: há uma regulação, um regulador, um papel oficial ou algo do tipo sobre pontuações, ou será que é apenas costume? Acho que é apenas convenção/costume, mas com recomendações de cada país. Se eu não me engano, a ABNT recomenda algumas pontuações, dando-lhes o significado, mas não é errado usar outra, assim como não é errado usar aspas alemãs no Brasil, mas não é recomendado e não se pode esperar alguém conhecer ou achar correto. Por aspas alemãs poderem se considerar erradas e “«” serem corretas, imagino que seja de caso a caso quão correto está o sinal.

Comment: Schilive, sabe dizer para que serve essas aspas («)? Já as vi sendo usadas por brasileiros, mas não sei o que significam, nem se usaram-nas num conceito certo.

Comment: @renanlinux, essas aspas são semanticamente equivalentes às nossas aspas. Interessante notar que elas são como negrito e itálico, podem se juntar; ex.: “eu falei pro Fernando «não te esqueças do que a Maria te falou. Ela falou ‹compra o pão›», mas ele esqueceu o pão” ou “eu falei pro Fernando ‘não te esqueças do que a Maria te falou. Ela falou «compra o pão»’, mas ele esqueceu o pão” ou «eu falei pro Fernando ‹não te esqueças do que a Maria te falou. Ela falou “compra pão”›, mas ele esqueceu o pão», etc.

Comment: @renanlinux, qual usar é questão de estilo (https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/as-aspas-em-linha--e-as-aspas-elevadas-/30497).

Comment: Hey, @renanlinux e Schilive, será que seria o caso de transformar esses últimos comentários sobre as aspas em pergunta & reposta? Se já não houver no site, me parece bem pertinente.

Comment: @stafusa, já existe: https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1613/when-to-use-or-italic.